# why symfony4 swiftmailer with gmail doesn't work?

Tags: swiftmailer, symfony-4.2

I don't understand why swiftmailer doesn't work with gmail?

I get this exception:

```
 ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

Here is MAILER_URL in .env file:

```
MAILER_URL="gmail://**********@gmail.com:Password@localhost"
```

===> My password contains some special characters like '@'. What i have to do in this case?? Maybe it is why it doesn't work?

Here is swiftmailer.yaml:

```
swiftmailer:
url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

I already try to disable Avast...Clear cache...not working...

But when i try with an another smtp like 'smtp.orange.fr', everything work fine.

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

if the username, password or host contain any character considered special in a URI (such as +, @, $, #, /, :, *, !), you must encode them. See RFC 3986 for the full list of reserved characters or use the urlencode function to encode them.